# Display SQL Table records that have matching data from different table

Tags: sql, database

I am very new to SQL, and I am trying to filter a set of records from one table based on matching columns from another table. 
Here is an example of what I would like to do:
I have two tables, I'll call them TableA and TableB. 
I have already applied a search on both Tables to filter their separate results down, but I want to filter TableA based on matching records from TableB.
TableA:
[image]

TableB:
[image]

Desired Result in TableA format:
[image]

TableB and TableA have matching ID columns, and I only want to display the records in TableA if the records also appear in TableB, but I need them to appear in TableA format.

Comment: A simple JOIN. Or EXISTS/IN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo need to do something like

```
Select a.id, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.birthday, a.ssn from TableA a, Table b where a.id=b.id
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 1):

A simple join would accomplish this.

```
select TableA.* from TableA inner join TableB on TableB.ID = TableA.IB
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (select 1 from b where a.id = b.id);
```